# Lithium select options from mysql data

Tags: php, mysql, lithium

I have a MySQL table `categories` with following columns:

- id
- name

I retrieved the data using

```
$categories = Categories::find('all');
```

Now, I want to create a `<select>` tag with options whose value is `$category->id` and title is `$category->name` using form helper.

How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `$categories = Categories::find('list');`

Comment: Thank you Lahman. It works perfectly. That is exactly what I wanted. :)

Comment: +1 for reminding me that `name` can be used in place of `title`.

Answer (score 1):

To complement Mehdi's answer, supposing you didn't want the field `Categories.name` to appear in your select list and instead, you wanted the field `Categories.code` to appear as the value of the select list, you could do this:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Categories extends \lithium\data\Model {

    protected $_meta = array('title' => 'code');
}
?>
```

Now, if you tried using the solution Mehdi gave you, you'd see `Categories.code` appear as the value instaed of `Categories.name`.

Also, from the [source of lithium/data/Model.php](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/data/Model.php#L202) regarding the `title` key:

> `title`: The field or key used as the title for each record. Defaults to `'title'` or
>   `'name'`, if those fields are available.